# What is correct way to handle form submission in beego?

Tags: go, form-submit, beego

I'm trying to submit form data in beego and store it to database. And have some questions:

- how correct handle request and transform it to object?
- Should I validate request or transformed object?

My controller action:

```
func (c *ServicesController) Edit() {
    var err error
    var id, _ = c.GetUint64(":id")
    var serviceModel = models.Service{}
    var service models.Service

    service, err = serviceModel.FindById(id)

    c.Data["Service"] = service

    if err == orm.ErrNoRows || err == orm.ErrMissPK  {
        c.Abort("404")
    }

    if c.Ctx.Input.IsPost() {
        err = nil
        if err := c.ParseForm(&service); err != nil {
            c.Abort("500")
        }

        serviceModel.CreateOrUpdate(service)
    }

    c.TplName = "services/edit.html"
}
```

Model:

```
type Service struct {
    Id       uint64 `form:"-"`
    Name     string `orm:"size(100)" valid:"Required; MaxSize(100)" form:"name"`
}

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(Service))
}

func (s *Service) FindById(id uint64) (Service, error) {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    service := Service{Id: id}
    err := o.Read(&service)

    return service, err
}

func (s *Service) CreateOrUpdate(service Service)  {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    o.InsertOrUpdate(&service)
}
```

But when I'm trying to submit form (with `InsertOrUpdate`) it anyway creates new object because I have no id field in the form (because I retrieving object from id param from route). Should I pass id to form anyway or how to hack it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the ID after you parse the form:

```
if err := c.ParseForm(&service); err != nil {
    c.Abort("500")
}
service.Id = id
```

Looking through beego's source, I *think* you could do:

```
if c.Ctx.Input.IsPost() {
    c.Input().Add("id", id)
    err = nil
    if err := c.ParseForm(&service); err != nil {
        c.Abort("500")
    }

    serviceModel.CreateOrUpdate(service)
}
```

But if not, I would just restructure your code a little bit:

```
func (c *ServicesController) Edit() {
    var id, _ = c.GetUint64(":id")
    var service models.Service{}
    var serviceModel = models.Service{}
    var err error

    if c.Ctx.Input.IsPost() {
        if err = c.ParseForm(&service); err != nil {
            c.Abort("500")
        }
        service.Id = id
        serviceModel.CreateOrUpdate(service)
    } else {
        service, err = serviceModel.FindById(id)
        if err == orm.ErrNoRows || err == orm.ErrMissPK  {
        c.Abort("404")
    }

    c.Data["Service"] = service
    c.TplName = "services/edit.html"
}
```

Comment: I also think about it, but is it not ugly? I get object from database and apply form data to it. Why it override id which is not in form?

Comment: You'd have to show us your `ParseForm` method, I have no idea why it overwrites it

Comment: It's not mine, it from beego